# Haskell function returning Just pair of values if both arguments are Just, Nothing otherwise

Tags: haskell, option-type

> Define a function
>
> ```
>    pairMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe (a,b)
> ```
>
> that produces a `Just` result only if both arguments are `Just`, and a `Nothing` if either argument is `Nothing`.

I’ve come up with:

```
pairMaybe (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a,b)
pairMaybe (Just a) Nothing = Nothing
pairMaybe Nothing (Just b) = Nothing
```

I’m not sure if this is the right way of writing it. Is there something wrong with this or is this the way to define this function?

Also I think I’d probably like a better explanation of what this function can actually *do*, so if I called `pairMaybe` with two arguments, what arguments can they be? Of course they have to be of type `Maybe`, but what’s a good example?

Comment: If you want to know whether the code works or not, you can enter it into a file and load it into GHCi with `:load yourfile.hs` and test the function yourself. If you are asking for code review (i.e. expert opinion and suggestions for improvement) you have unfortunately ended up on the wrong site! You might have better luck on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I know how to check if the code works, and it does but i'm more thinking what it actually is meant to do, not if it compiles or not

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing this via pattern matching is fine; you could simplify your code though by using

```
pairMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe (a,b)
pairMaybe (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a,b)
pairMaybe _        _        = Nothing
```

That being said, your function actually just lifts the `(,)` function (which creates 2-tuples) into the `Maybe` monad, so you could also write

```
pairMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe (a,b)
pairMaybe = liftM2 (,)
```

Comment: Also, any idea how it would be tested? I tried something like pairMaybe 5 6 but if complains about it cannot infer types...

Comment: @SuzanAydın: Well `pairMaybe 5 6` doesn't type check, you probably meant `pairMaybe (Just 5) (Just 6)`. That being said, make sure to include a type signature if you're using the `liftM2`-based version, since otherwise the compiler cannot decide what type signature to infer.

Answer (score 6):

You missed the pattern where both values are `Nothing` (that won't match to any of your patterns):

```
pairMaybe Nothing Nothing = Nothing
```

Other than that pattern matching is a great way of getting things done in Haskell.

Comment: Hey, silly me forgetting that... but other than that that's actually ok? :) Sorry i'm a bit shocked, very new to haskell

Comment: @SuzanAydın: With this addition, it's perfectly correct, though you actually only need two cases: `pairMaybe (Just a) (Just b)` and `pairMaybe _ _` — since all other cases give the same result, you can just lump them together.

Comment: @SuzanAydın yes, looks fine to me. I think `pairMaybe` could be used to check whether two values are present and, if not, proceed with `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks great! Though you can shorten it a bit.

```
pairMaybe (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a,b)
pairMaybe _        _        = Nothing
```

This also fixes the bug Simeon pointed out. The reason you can simplify it like that is that all the right hand sides with `Nothing` are the same, so those cases can be merged into one.